# SQL. Сравнение с последующим объединением наборов

Tags: sql, postgresql, сравнение, объединение

В таблице есть два столбца: ID , номер группы в которую он входит.
Столкнулся с проблемой, что, например в группе 1 может быть 3 ID, которые будут входить также и во 2 группу.
Вот пример:

```
ID | group   
1 | 1  
2 | 1   
3 | 1     
4 | 2    
5 | 2     
1 | 2   
2 | 2   
3 | 2    
8 | 3   
6 | 3
```

И так далее.

Хочу написать запрос, который будет проверять количество совпадений одной группы с другой и в случае совпадения на более, чем 50% объединять ID в одну группу (например еще один столбик с новыми группами).
Подскажите, как это можно реализовать на sql?
UP: На выходе из алгоритма мы должны получить непересекающиеся более, чем на 50% группы. То есть внутри кода может быть несколько итераций по объединению групп.

Answer (score 0):

Задача плохо определена.

Пример.

Имеем группы

```
1 (1, 2)
2 (2, 3) 
3 (3, 4) 
4 (2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7)
```

Если объединим группы 1 и 2 (они имеют по 50% соответствий), получим

```
12 (1, 2, 3)
3 (3, 4) 
4 (2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7)
```

На этом объединение завершится.

---

Но если объединить сначала группы 2 и 3 (они тоже имеют по 50% соответствий), получим

```
1 (1, 2)
23 (2, 3, 4) 
4 (2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7)
```

и можно объединить полученную группу с группой 4 (имеем 50% соответствия), получая в итоге

```
1 (1, 2)
234 (2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7)
```

Comment: Да, вы правы, что неточно написан вопрос.     
Кстати, в вашем примере получается, что во втором случае в конце еще объединятся группы
1 (1, 2) и 234 (2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7) в 1234 (1,2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7)

Интересует второй вариант, когда мы проделывает несколько итераций, до тех пор, пока не останутся группы, которые нельзя объединить.

Comment: @OPTIKAL *Кстати, в вашем примере получается, что во втором случае в конце еще объединятся группы* То есть *и в случае совпадения на более, чем 50% объединять ID в одну группу* - это "если для хотя бы одной из групп более 50%"? ну совсем ох...

Comment: На выходе хочется получить уникальные более, чем на 50% группы после нескольких итераций объединения

Comment: @OPTIKAL Задача по сути - итерационная, с неопределённым количеством итераций. Решение в формате запроса мне кажется сомнительным. А вот решение в формате хранимой процедуры, с использованием нескольких временных таблиц, вполне может существовать. Однако следует как минимум сформулировать критерий приоритета объединения - ибо каждое очередное объединение может, как показано в ответе, исключить возможность объединения группы.

Comment: Порядок объединения: вначале сравниваем (объединяем) маленькие группы. А итерационные алгоритмы вообще реализуемы на sql?

Comment: @OPTIKAL Когда я говорил "сформулировать критерий", я имел в виду, что он должен давать однозначный ответ типа "на этом шаге мы объединяем именно группу X именно с группой Y". Т.е. даже в случае равнозначных пар (см. выше - пары 1+2 и 2+3 по признаку "маленькие" равнозначны). *итерационные алгоритмы вообще реализуемы на sql?* Формально да. Реально - как правило, полученное решение трудно считать оптимальным.

Comment: Ищем две самые маленькие группы, расставляя их по номеру сравниваемой (первой) группы в порядке возрастания, то есть в случае "см. выше - пары 1+2 и 2+3 по признаку "маленькие" равнозначны" приоритет будет у пары 1+2, тк их номер первой группы к 0.
Объединяем группы, присваивая номер младшей из групп, прогоняем алгоритм снова.
Когда не останется групп с совпадением >50%, то переприсваиваем номера в зависимости от количества ID внутри группы, первыми будут большие группы, если совпадение по количеству ID, то рандомно (либо любое правило) выбираем любую в качестве первой.

Comment: Ну вот теперь реализуйте это в формате хранимой процедуры. Берёте две копии таблицы, выбираете ту самую минимальную пару, копируете объединение этих групп во временную таблицу, удаляете эту пару, копируете на её место объединённую. Повторяете, пока объединяется.

Comment: Звучит крайне сложно, так как никогда не работал с хранимыми процедурами и даже временными таблицами. Что посоветуете почитать? Или может есть подсказки по коду? Работаю в web среде [periscope](http://periscopedata.com). Надеюсь там есть такой функционал.

Comment: @OPTIKAL *Что посоветуете почитать?* Кроме [MySQL Reference](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/) в общем ничего не нужно. *может есть подсказки по коду?* Да вроде все возможные подсказки уже даны... дальше можно подсказывать уже по существующей реализации (коду процедуры), которой нет. *Надеюсь там есть такой функционал.* Более чем сомнительно.